# add new property in model file of a active record in Yii

Tags: model, yii

I am new in Yii framework and have a question.

I have a table named 'node' which has these fields:

- id
- name
- parent_id

parent_id contain id of parent of a node which exist in this table too.

I have created model,controller and view files using Gii interface. In view files id of parent is shown but I want to display parent name instead of its id .

I guess maybe I need to add a public property in model class of this table, so I would be access to it via ->parent_name in view files.

How can I do it ? what files should I change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a relation to your parent node.

So in your Node::relations function, you should have something like:

```
'parent' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Node', 'parent_id'),
```

To get this value from your child, you can do (assuming your child node variable is named $childNode):

```
echo $childNode->parent->name;
```

If you really want to be able to do...

```
$childNode->parent_name;
```

... for some reason, you can create a property in your Node model like this:

```
public function getParent_name()
{
    if ($this->parent == null)
        return '';

    return $this->parent->name;
}
```

Now you can call...

```
$childNode->parent_name;
```

OR

```
$childName->getParent_name();
```

to get the name of the parent node.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a Parent for `parent` table and relation like:

```
'parent' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Parent', 'parent_id)
```

or

```
'parent' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Node', 'parent_id'),
```

If it's relation to the same table. And then you'll be able to access the parent name like this:

```
echo CHtml::value($node, 'parent.name');
```

Comment: I don't have a parent table. parent is also in node table.