# return some joined fields in CActiveDataProvider

Tags: join, yii, cactivedataprovider

My question is related to Yii framework.

I have defined relations in a model class . How can I return some specific fields of the join in CActiveDataProvider ?

Comment: `CActiveDataProvider` accepts a pre-constructed query. For example: `$finder = Post::model(); $finder->with('Comment.Author'); $finder->condition = 't.published = 1'; $provider = new CActiveDataProvider($finder);` will give the data provider access to the results of that query. Then you should have access to those relations same as if you had queried them yourself.

Comment: I dont think you would need this on your data provider, what is it you really want?

Comment: Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070053/add-new-property-in-model-file-of-a-active-record-in-yii  It was my first question